# What Should I Accept for Termite Control for a New Construction Home?

Tags: code-compliance, usa, termite, texas

I am building a new home with a rigid steel structure + steel roof/siding, and traditional 2x4 wood framing on inside, a.k.a. a "barndominium".  Regarding termite prevention, applicable (?!) code appears to be this (year 2018; section language essentially unchanged from previous version year 2015):

[R318.1Subterranean termite control methods.](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IRC2018P4/chapter-3-building-planning/IRC2018P4-Ch03-SecR318.1)

My preference is a typical/standard treatment of all wood framing, especially those located on exterior sides, but my General Contractor/builder will *certainly* try to do the least cost approach, no matter what that means to the home, and the nature of contract is that I'll have little say in the matter as long as it conforms to applicable code.

*But I am a bit confused as to just ***what*** is the necessary and sufficient approach in my specific case, code-wise, that my builder is likely to want to do (i.e. "get away with")?*  Hence this question...

The home is in Texas, USA, and outside any city limits/jurisdiction.  LAHJ (local authority having jurisdiction is probably the county in which home is located.  I have a phone call into them but they will likely not want to actually advise me on how to proceed.  And I have had an independent home inspection done recently which raised this point, but as a matter of liability they don't suggest a specific course of action.

---

edit: apparently it needs clarification:  the kernel of main question is given description of my home build and applicable code, what is the "least efforts" and/or "least cost" approach to be taken regarding termite protection.

Anyone deciding to respond, please don't get caught up with pedantics or unfounded assumptions or "I would never ask this so you shouldn't either" mindsets.  Thanks.

Comment: @jay613: The AHJ is somewhat aside to my question, but as mentioned it is likely the county and their participation, if any, would be inspection for code.  I realize I can pay to have anything done I want, e.g. my preferred treatment.  The code is clear; and what I asked, clearly, is what approach that meets code would be a least-efforts approach.  Additionally, you've assumed way too much with your response.  If you don't want to attempt a reasonable answer, that's fine, but what's the point in undermining a fair question that I and others may benefit from?  That's what this forum is for.

Comment: @jay613: I can sorta see how you came to that thought, but you don't know me or know how much extra I've paid for out of pocket on this project to get what I wanted. (short answer: a lot!).  I've edited my original with comment that hopefully bottom-lines my question.  Comments most likely to get my upvote or marked as solution will come from folks experienced in actually applying or interpreting this sort of code, e.g. licensed contractors or code inspectors, as opposed to people making educated guesses (I can do that for myself).  Thanks.

Comment: Title question: What should "accept" or what should you "expect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treatment of the wood framing is not the norm and only needed if active termites are present. It has a lifespan and can be useless for a new home. Giving the feeling of security from termites, when in fact it is a waste, because it will be ineffective in the future.

I'm in Florida but I would think Texas is the same where the builder has the soil treated prior to pouring a slab. (the chemical termicidal treatment option in the control methods.) This usually carries a 1 to 3 year warranty.

Then it is up to you to have new treatment done when needed. Most locales have regulation against putting chemicals in the soil too often. So you cannot even legally pay to have the soil treated around your home unless a determined time has passed.